# Condition for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am using 2 JComboBoxes

```
String arr1[] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};
String arr2[] = {"text1", "text2", "text3"};

JComboBox box1 = new JComboBox(arr1);
JComboBox box2 = new JComboBox(arr2);
```

where I am looking for conditions like

```
if(text1 in box1 is selected)
only text2 and text3 is selectable/enabled in box2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value from the *JComboBox* you use [getSelectedItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29):

```
String value = (String)box.getSelectedItem();
```

Now you can check if `value` equals to `text1`, if so, you can use [removeItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeItem%28java.lang.Object%29) to remove items from the other *JComboBox*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an action listener to `box1` and control what is shown/enabled in `box2`

```
box1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             // code to manipulate values in box2 depending upon value in `box1Value`
            String box1Value = txtFilename.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(box1Value.equalsIgnoreCase("text1")){
                String arr2[] = { "text2", "text3"};
                new JComboBox(arr2);
            } else {
                // ..
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `Disable` an item in your `JComboBox` without delete it  , Like that :

[image]

So You can try [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/DisabledComboBoxExample.htm)